# ActiveMQ (MQTT) maxes CPU on first client connect

Tags: activemq-classic, mqtt

I'm running ActiveMQ (a very recent version) on LinuxMint 15 using oracle 1.7 java. I've only enabled a single transport "mqtt+nio+ssl". It boots up fine, ssl is all working, easy!

However, when I make a (mqtt) connection from the same host (different java process), the activemq process starts to consume a whole core. It keeps the core at 100% until I stop it (it stops normally). This sounds like abnormal behaviour to me, but when I turned on debug logging I got nothing that seemed to suggest massive CPU consumption.

Has anyone else seen or resolved this problem?

Can anyone suggest how I should go about analyzing this problem?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously this is some sort of bug in ActiveMQ.  There's been a lot of work done on the MQTT and AMQP side for the upcoming release of v5.9.0.  You can download snapshots builds or the [release candidate of](https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/orgapacheactivemq-171/org/apache/activemq/apache-activemq/5.9.0/) 5.9 and test that to see if it still does this.  If it still acts like this then you need to create an issue in the Jira tracker so the team can work on it, preferably with a test case to reproduce it.

Comment: Thanks Tim :-) This is kinda what I suspected. I've since shifted to mosquitto and didn't get a chance to test 5.9.